# Simplify 2 Java variables into one

Tags: java, pi

I've got these 2 Java variables:

```
spiEuler = spiEuler + (1 / Math.pow(2 * k + 1, 2));
piEuler = Math.sqrt(spiEuler * 8);
```

...and I'd like to combine them into one.
Unfortunately,

```
piCombined = Math.sqrt((xPi + (1 / Math.pow(2 * k + 1, 2))) * 8);
```

doesn't do that. What did I do wrong here?

Comment: It doesn't do that? What *does* it do? What did you expect?

Answer (score 0):

the most you can get is

```
spiEuler += (1 / Math.pow(2 * k + 1, 2));
```

and then

```
piEuler = Math.sqrt(spiEuler * 8);
```